# Migration and deployement problems JBoss 4.2.2.GA to JBoss 6.0.0.M2

Tags: java, jboss, upgrade, jboss6.x

I'm trying to migrate an application running on JBoss 4.2.2.GA to JBoss 6.0.0.M2
I give you some log to explain my problem :

boot.log :

```
2010-03-16 09:59:29,406 ERROR [org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap] (Thread-2) Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/G:/jboss-6.0.0.M2/server/default/deploy/serveur.jar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Factory$org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor is already installed.
```

server.log :

```
11:58:33,156 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfszip:/G:/jboss-6.0.0.M2/server/default/deploy/serveur.jar/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:196)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:95)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1660)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1378)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1431)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:918)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:633)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:898)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:677)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:873)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:620)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:259)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:100)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:860)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: common.Main from BaseClassLoader@e1c3a7{vfszip:/G:/jboss-6.0.0.M2/server/default/deploy/serveur.jar/}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:498)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processJBossClientMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:105)
    at org.jboss.deployment.OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.processMetaData(OptAnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:73)
    at org.jboss.deployment.AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.deploy(AnnotationMetaDataDeployer.java:192)
    ... 34 more

11:58:40,828 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:10900/jmxconnector
11:58:46,500 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
11:58:46,593 ERROR [NamingProviderURLWriter] Cannot create a naming service URL file at file:/G:/jboss-6.0.0.M2/server/default/data/jnp-service.url: java.io.IOException: Accès refusé
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
    at org.jboss.naming.NamingProviderURLWriter.start(NamingProviderURLWriter.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:873)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:620)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:180)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1660)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1378)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1399)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1319)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:918)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:633)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:898)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:677)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:378)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2029)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1050)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1289)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1213)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:873)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:620)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:259)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:100)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:860)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

this application works fine on JBoss 4.2.2.GA, if someone have any idea, I need some help.

Comment: JBoss 6 already?  Lord, I'm getting seriously behind again....

Comment: I would try it with JBoss 5.1 first, maybe this will show (and filter out) some easy to fix problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue ["Windows file locking problem with the data/jnp-service.url file"](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7674) in JBoss-6.0.0.M2.

You should update to newer version of JBoss or manually unlock the jnp-service.url file (using Unlocker tool), it turns out cidaemon.exe was locking the file. Another solution is to turn off the Indexing Service.

See also ["Adventures with JBoss"](http://www.brianmokeefe.com/node/9) article.